# Android Hilt scope for fragment ViewModel

Tags: android, scope, components, dagger-hilt

In the doc, you can see this graph:
[image]

So there is this "ActivityRetainedScope" for activity ViewModel, but what about fragment ViewModel? What is the right scope to be used in this case? And the same question for the component, I don't see a component for the fragment ViewModel?

Comment: Can you please explain your use case ?
AFAIK, `ActivityRetainedComponent` is an `ActivityComponent` that will survive configuration change. Though, if you use view models, you don't really need to worry about configuration change: your view model will only be created (and its fields injected) once.

Comment: How about just using @ViewModelInject? It should work in both Activity and Fragments.